# Hazelcast ReplicatedMap and property change

Tags: hazelcast

Is there any interface for Hazelcast (something like `PropertyChanged` event) which would notify it when any property in cached object changes so it's replicated via cluster?
I am updating entire objects within map so I wonder if there is any automatic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no listener which will tell you about specific properties being changed since Hazelcast atomically exchanges the whole, serialized, object and doesn't even know about properties.

Comment: My point is whether there is any way how to tell Hazelcast to update all instances accross cluster should some event happen on given object. Like if there is possibility to implement some interface with event, which Hazelcast knows and updates all instances in replicated map in case that event is fired on mapped object.

Comment: Like if I implement some interface `INotifyHazelcastThatObjectHasBeenUpdated` which would provide some listener for hazelcast to inject its own handler and manage update accross cluster

Comment: Sorry I still don't get the idea. If you have "some" listener and you want to update the instance in a Hazelcast ReplicatedMap, just write the object (inside the eventlistener) to the RM. Do I miss something?